# how to check the quantity of products in the woocommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

The code checks if the shipping class is equal to id 53 and hides the shipping method.
The problem is that: if someone adds more than one product, the code checks only in the last added item.
I would like it to count all added products first and if there are more than 2 products with the same shipping class, then it will hide the "pack locker" shipping method
Please help

```
`add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'fanka_kodowania_hide_shipping_method1', 10, 2 );

function fanka_kodowania_hide_shipping_method1( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    /*****************KLASA WYSYŁKI**************************/
    $class1 = 53;
    /********************************************************/

    /*****************METODY WYSYŁKI*************************/
    $method_key_ids = array('inpost_paczkomaty:12');
    /********************************************************/

    global $woocommerce; 

    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        
        $item = $cart_item['data'];

        if(!empty($item)) {
            $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];
                
        }
    }



    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ) {

        if( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class1 && $quantity >1 ){
            foreach( $method_key_ids as $method_key_id ){
                unset($rates[$method_key_id]);
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}
`
```

Answer (score 1):

This check checks the last item in the cart when determining if the shipping method should be hidden.

Add a check for quantity:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'fanka_kodowania_hide_shipping_method1', 10, 2 );

function fanka_kodowania_hide_shipping_method1( $rates, $package )
{
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Shipping class to check for
    $class1 = 53;

    // Shipping method to hide
    $method_key_ids = array('inpost_paczkomaty:12');

    // Keep track of the quantity of items with the specified shipping class
    $quantity = 0;

    foreach( $package['contents'] as $item ) {
        if( $item['data']->get_shipping_class_id() == $class1 ){
            $quantity += $item['quantity'];
        }
    }

    // If there are more than two items with the specified shipping class, hide the shipping method
    if( $quantity > 1 ) {
        foreach( $method_key_ids as $method_key_id ){
            unset($rates[$method_key_id]);
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
```

Comment: WOW! Thanks a lot everything works :)

Comment: @DamianMordarski - you're welcome. If it's correct, please mark the answer.